# Magento 1.9 : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: magento-1.9, database, extensions

[image]

I have one used advertisement purpose Magento extension in website,when i click on upload Images Button then make this error.

Please help me Developers,Thanks

Error :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`carparts_mage`.`#sql-952f8_1ffc720`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT_1_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For avoiding forign key set `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;` before uploading database and then later after importing change it back to `SET foreign_key_checks = 1;`

Comment: This post doesn't seem to be about uploading a database at all, rather it seems to be some kind of integrity constraint affecting a journey clicking through the UI.